# Rails child object using parent method instead of its own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the Child class `Vibe::Interaction::SurveyMessage` that inherits from `Interaction`. They share the same table, and the `SurveyMessage` is identified by `{app: :vibe, kind:"survey"}`.

The controller calls the method through the parent class:
`Interaction.find(param[:id]).refresh`

The problem is that even when the object is a `SurveyMessage Object`, it uses the parent's `update_message` method (the empty one).

Is there a way to force the object to act as a `SurveyMessage Object` instantiating it with the parent class (`Interaction`)?
Or is there a way to identify through the parent class if the object belongs to a child class?

```
class Interaction < ApplicationRecord
  enum app: [ :praise, :review, :vibe, :atlas, :goals ]
  belongs_to :survey, class_name: 'Survey', foreign_key: :vibe_survey_id, required: false
  serialize :attachments 

  def message
    {
      text: self.text,
      attachments: self.attachments
    }
  end

  def update_message
  end

  def refresh(options = {})
    update_message
    h = self.history << {
            :type => :refresh,
            :timestamp => Time.current.to_s
          }
    update( 
      history: h 
    )
    # Submit code
    message
  end

end
```

```
class Vibe::Interaction::SurveyMessage < Interaction
  default_scope -> { where(app: :vibe, kind: "survey") }

  def update_message
    msg = survey.answer(user_id, self, additional_options||{} )
    update( text: msg[:text], attachments: msg[:attachments])
  end

end
```

Comment: try `Vibe::Interaction::SurveyMessage.find(param[:id]).refresh`

Comment: Don't use the scope resolution operator (`::`) when defining nested classes. This will lead to nasty surprises as it depends on the module nesting at the point of definition. In this case its the global scope. So when you reference `Interaction` inside `Vibe::Interaction::SurveyMessage` you'll actually get `::Interaction` instead of `Vibe::Interaction`. Use using explicit nesting and reopen the modules `module Vibe; class Interaction; class SurveyMessage < Interaction ...`. https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Comment: Hey @PGill! If I use `Vibe::Interaction::SurveyMessage.find(param[:id])` it will work, but I would like to use the parent `Interaction.find()` in the controller, as I will have a lot of different childs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `becomes` method

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes

If your subclasses have a pattern

```
i = Interaction.find_by(id: id)
i = i.becomes("#{i.kind.capitalize}Message".constantize) if i&.vibe? # or in parent class as a method #downcast
i.refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it creating a router method on the parent `Interaction` :

```
  def self.find_child(id)
    i = Interaction.find_by(id: id)
    if i&.vibe? and i.kind=="survey"
      ans = Vibe::Interaction::SurveyMessage.find(id)
    elsif i&.vibe? and i.kind=="partial"
      ans = Vibe::Interaction::PartialMessage.find(id)
    elsif (etc)
      ...
    else
      ans = i
    end
    ans
  end
```

It's not elegant but it works. If anyone has a better solution I'd love to hear about.